# Possible to hide a button on particular language in iOS with base localization?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I'm new to localization. I've got my app mostly converted, but I have a case where a button only appears in the US English version of the app, but no other languages. Is this possible using main.strings and localizable.strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jakub Vano's answer is pretty useful, but also you can set that string with a special value as "notToShow" and do this

```
if ([NSLocalizedString(@"MyString", nil) isEqual:@"notToShow"]){
        //hide button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking code, you can check current locale via

```
[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]
```

and show / hide button accordingly. If you are using storyboard / xib, you can have separate interface for each localization.